# How to restore a Default Display Form (DispForm.aspx)

Tags: javascript, restore, dispform

In my Default Display form I had previous added a webpart which included javascript code to suppress some of the form fields - all good so far.

Today, I wanted to add a webpart to display a list view, after I added the list view web part I got an error on the page, I then clicked stopped editing.

Problem: when I went back to edit the Default Display Form, I am presented with blank/white space in the area of the page where previously the editable form would appear. The screen still displays the top ribbon, left-side navigation menu, just no form which I can edit.

Preference #1 - is there a way to roll back to the previous version of the form?

Preference #2 - is it possible to edit the DispForm.aspx file to remove the list and javascript webparts

Preference #3 - how can I reload/reset the display form back to factory default?

Note: I do not have access to InfoPath nor SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open Web Parts Maintenance Page and remove added web parts from display form.
Just add **?contents=1** to url of display form.

http://*YOUR SITE URL*/Lists/*LIST NAME*/DispForm.aspx?contents=1

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was able to delete the webpart I added. It didn't impact my javascript webpart. It displayed normally again, and editing went back to normal. Thank you.